# Post doc to CouchDB from Quasar Vue3 Axios

Tags: vue.js, rest, axios, couchdb, quasar

I have tried a few methods and have not been able to get it to work.
The base URL is in the Axios setup file and logging in out it console shows the correct address.
Replicating works when using PouchDB but in this case, I didn't want to use Pouchd, there is no need to save local only want to post.

I get this error with this code:
" 401 (Unauthorized)"
" Error: Request failed with status code 401"

```
api({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/webdata",
    data: doc,
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
  })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("result: ", result);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("e: ", e);
    });
```

I get this error with this code:
"Error on Authentication  Error: Request failed with status code 400"

```
  var username = <user>;
  var password = <pass>;
  var credentials = window.btoa(username + ":" + password);

  var basicAuth = "Basic " + credentials;
  api
    .post("/webdata", {
      headers: { Authorization: basicAuth },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Authenticated ", response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error on Authentication ", error);
    });
```

It even fails when I use admin user/pass

I also used Postman and it will work if I add id and "/json"

```
http://<ip>:5984/webdata/<test::id>/json
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `+basicAuth`? is that a typo in the post or in the actual code? If the latter that value will be NaN.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to only  basicAuth and now I get error "Error on Authentication  Error: Request failed with status code 400"

Comment: I am assuming `/webdata` is a db endpoint?  That would be interesting since a 400 response to a db endpoint means "Invalid database name".

Comment: yes that is the db name (webdata) , I can sync to that db with pouchdb on another app.

Comment: my other app with Pouchdb is in angularjs and works but this app without PouchDB in vuejs gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in the syntax:

```
  api({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/webdata",
    data: doc,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("result: ", result);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("e: ", e);
    });
```

I removed the "headers: { Authorization: basicAuth }," and "headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },"  I had already added it in the axios config.
Also, I made sure I had an _id inside the doc.